# Using Google API in Angular 4

Tags: angular, google-api

I am trying to connect to google API through http get service in Angular 4, however, I cannot access. The code looks like the following:

```
const requestHeaders = new Headers();
requestHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: requestHeaders });
const myURL = 'https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:' +
    'search?query=taylor+swift&key=MYKEY&limit=1&indent=True';
return this.http.get(myURL, options)
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
.subscribe(
    data => console.log(data),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('output')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your above code looks good except two things to take care here.

1. `RequestOptions` is not mandatory here. So avoid using it. The http request will trigger without `RequestOptions` too until you need it specifically.
2. See the value of `Content-type` which should be proper as per
   the **data type** of  returning result by google-api.

**Below is my code sample which is working properly.**

- MyService.ts file

  `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
  let httpRequestHeaders = new Headers();
  httpRequestHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  GetMyData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('myURL ', httpRequestHeaders);
  }`
- some.Component.ts file

  `SomeMethod() {
      this.MyService.GetMyData()
      .subscribe((resp) => {
         console.log(resp);
        },
        err => {
         //this.logger.LogError('Erro while fetching data');
        });
    }`

Comment: you can not use httpRequestHeaders inside of http get, you should use: const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: requestHeaders }); and use option inside of the code --. this.http.get(myURL, options)